# Send a keyboard key to another application

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I have an old dictation app on Windows, that (when in focus) will start playback by pressing F9.

When I am writing in Word, I have to switch to the dictation app, press F9 and then click on the Word window to start typing.

Is there a way to send a key (F9 in this case) to an application which is not on the front?

Comment: Autohotkey seems like it would do the job.

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks. Never used it. I see the "Send" events, but only works with the active window. Is there a similar command? Or should I activate the other app, send the key and then activate Word again?

Comment: I thought that there was a version of Send that took a window title for one off work but can't find it. Typically though you would indeed activate the other window, do a Winwaitactive or similar and then send the keys. Bonus points for getting the title of the current window and reactivating it after. I may have a look and see how easy it is tonight. You can achieve similar in Word VBA I believe using "AppActivate" and "SendKeys" but the constraints are similar. It would at least keep you in Word rather than using another application.

Comment: try Autoit ....

Comment: @Mokubai Works perfectly with Autohotkey & Send with the first part of the Windows Title! Post it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @Matteo if you have actual code then I'm happy for you to post the answer yourself, I got distracted and didn't follow through. My comments were little more than "I think you might be able to use..."

Answer (score 2):

I managed with AutoHotkey and the following script:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

^j::
ControlSend ,,{f9}, Beginning of the window's title
return
```